# PHP Ternary statement not working

Tags: php

```
 $string = '';
  $q = $l = $count = $count1 = 0;
  // Query to get number of rows in table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $section4";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  mysqli_free_result();
  // Loop and switch statement for different "type"s of subsections in section
  while ($q <= 10) {
     // Reset values
     $test = $shown = false;
     $first = true;
     $count1 = ($q == 1 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 2 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 3 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 4 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 5 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 6 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 7 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 8 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 9 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $count1 = ($q == 10 ?: $count1 + $count);
     $group = $count = 0;
     $output = $numrows - $count1;


     $query = "SELECT * FROM $section4 LIMIT $output OFFSET $count1";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($first) {
           $prev = $row["type"];
           $first = false;
        } //$first
        if ($prev == $row["type"]) {
           $prev = $row["type"];
           $count++;
        } //$prev == $row["type"]
     } //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
     $query = "SELECT * FROM $section4 LIMIT $count OFFSET $count1";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (!in_array($row["classid"], $data)) {
           if (!$shown) {
              $string = $string . 'You need to take ' . $row["classname"] . ' (' . $row["classid"] . ')';
              $string1 = 'You need to take ' . $row["classname"] . ' (' . $row["classid"] . ')';
           } //!$shown
           else {
              $string.= ', and ' . $row["classname"] . ' (' . $row["classid"] . ')';
              $string1.= ', and ' . $row["classname"] . ' (' . $row["classid"] . ')';
           }
           $shown = true;
        } //!in_array($row["classid"], $data)
        else {
           array_push($taken, $row["classid"]);
           $totalhours = $totalhours + $row["classhours"];
           $group++;
        }
     } //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
     $group0 = ($q == 0) ? : $group;
     $group1 = ($q == 1) ? : $group;
     $group2 = ($q == 2) ? : $group;
     $group3 = ($q == 3) ? : $group;
     $group4 = ($q == 4) ? : $group;
     $group5 = ($q == 5) ? : $group;
     $group6 = ($q == 6) ? : $group;
     $group7 = ($q == 7) ? : $group;
     $group8 = ($q == 8) ? : $group;
     $group9 = ($q == 9) ? : $group;
     $group10 = ($q == 10) ? : $group;
     mysqli_free_result();
     if ($shown) {
        $string = $string . '. ';
        $l++;
        $str0 = ($q == 0) ? : $string1;
        $str1 = ($q == 1) ? : $string1;
        $str2 = ($q == 2) ? : $string1;
        $str3 = ($q == 3) ? : $string1;
        $str4 = ($q == 4) ? : $string1;
        $str5 = ($q == 5) ? : $string1;
        $str6 = ($q == 6) ? : $string1;
        $str7 = ($q == 7) ? : $string1;
        $str8 = ($q == 8) ? : $string1;
        $str9 = ($q == 9) ? : $string1;
        $str10 = ($q == 10) ? : $string1;
     } //$shown
     $q++;
  } //$q <= 10
```

My end goal is to have "$count1" be the offset for mySQL database query. $count1 is supposed to add "$count" to get an updated "$count1" value. However, when i echo $count1 it outputs this information:

`0
37
17
8
13
6
9
4
9
2
1`

I understand my code is sloppy, and so is the database. This is simply a school project that is due quite soon.

I'm trying to turn:

```
if($q = $value){ $count1 = $count1 + $count; }
```

to:

`$count1 = ($q == 1 ?: $count1 + $count);`

Comment: What's the values for $q and $count?

Comment: I can promise that it does _not_ print "what ever it wants". It prints what you tells it to. However, without any examples, there's absolutely _no way_ to answer this question. Add example values, expected results and actual results.

Comment: And please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What did you expected? What did you get?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: You may not realize what this is doing: `$count1 = ($q == 10 ?: $count1 + $count);` That is, really, "set `$count1` equal to `$q == 10` or, if it's falsey, `$count + $count`". `$q == 10` gives you a boolean, so you end up with `true`, or (!) `false` "falling through to" `$count1 + $count1`, and `true` will evaluate to `1`, so really `1` or `$count1 + $count1`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Intesting, I must have been misreading some examples, as stated in my question what would be the correct form if I'm looking to turn  if($q = $value){ $count1 = $count1 + $count; } to ternary?

Comment: It sure looks like `$q` is _always_ equal to `0` too, since it's never set after initialization that I can see.

Comment: There is a '$q++;' at the bottom adding to the while loop.

Comment: There were some typos and mistakes RE: variable names, I'm very tired. A regular ternary is this: `$var = conditional ? if true : if false` (psuedo code). I'm guessing what you really want is this: `$count1++` for each loop. However, if a ternary is required, `$count1 = $q == 1 ? $count1++ : $count1;` would seem right. In other words, the full form.

Comment: The short ternary form you're trying is different, the condition is the first value's "truthiness", in other words, if it evaluates as non-falsey, set it to that value, else do the other thing: `$var = $if_not_falsey_use_value ?: $set_something else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) says:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

Your expression:

```
$q == 1 ?: $count1 + $count
```

evaluates to the value of `$q == 1` if `$q == 1` evaluates to `TRUE` and to `$count1 + $count` otherwise.

Because `==` is a [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison), `$q == 1` always evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` (the *"evaluates to `TRUE`"* in the quoted documentation means "[equals to `TRUE` using loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)").

When `$q` is `1`, the value of the expression above is `TRUE` and this is probably not what you wanted.

It's not clear for me what exactly do you want to achieve. Anyway, the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) **is not** a shorter form of the [if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) as many people think.

Comment: This is right, including the "it's not clear what you're trying to do". `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Won't it be the easier?..

```
if ($q >= 1 && $q <= 10) {
    $count1 += $count;
}
```